# How to get a single document from firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to the documentation from firebase you can get a document very simply by using [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

But for some reason in my code it always displays that there's no such document, even though it does exist, this is what I'm doing:

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(user, "This is the user UID:"+user.uid)
    const userDoc = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid);
    const doc = userDoc.get();

    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
    }
    
    else {
    userDoc
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      
       const tempData = [];
       snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         
         const data = doc.data();
         tempData.push(data);
 
       });
       setUserData(tempData);
     })
    }
}, [user]);
```

This is what the `console.log()` shows:

[image]

This is how it looks in firebase:

[image]

Comment: The most common cause of this is that you have a non-visible character in the document ID, like a space before or after it. I'd recommend printing all document ID from your database with something like `console.log("'"+doc.id+"'")` to see where the mismatch may come from.

Comment: not the case, when I create a new user with `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` I also create a document for that user based on the UID like this:  `db.collection('usuarios').doc(auth.user.uid).set` and also adding the uid in the doc as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const doc = userDoc.get();

if (!doc.exists) {
```

`.get` returns a promise, so you're checking the `.exists` property on a promise, which is `undefined`. You will need to wait for that promise to resolve, either with `.then`:

```
userDoc.get().then(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    // etc
  }
});
```

Or by putting your code in an `async` function and `await`ing the promise:

```
const doc = await userDoc.get();

if (!doc.exists) {
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the firebase 8 web version, the `userDoc.get()` returns a promise, not the document:

```js
userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    const tempData = [];
    const data = doc.data();
    tempData.push(data);
    setUserData(tempData)
    console.log('it worked')
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

You can get more info about promises in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using the get method to fetch user data and get doesn't provide a snapshot. also, you missed that get() will return a promise so you have to handle using async-await or .then etc.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user, "This is the user UID:"+user.uid);
    getUser(user.uid).then(userData => {
      setUserData(userData);
    });
}, [user]);

const getUser = async (id) => {
  try {
    const user = await db.collection('usuarios').doc(id).get();
    const userData = user.data();
    return userData;
  } catch (err){
    console.log('Error during get user, No such document!');
    return  false;
}
```